# how to validate the fields education and moraleducation using js

Tags: javascript

the following code contains the code for education and moraleducation.i want to validate both the education and moral education fields when i click on a button.

```
$('body').on('change', '#education', function(){
        if( !$("#education").val() ) {

        $(this).closest('.form-group').addClass('has-error');

        }else{
        $(this).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-error');
        }
    });

        $('body').on('click', '#update', function(){
        if( !$("#education").val() ) { 

         $(this).closest('.form-group').addClass('has-error');

        }else{
        $(this).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-error');
        }
    });


      $('body').on('change', '#moraleducation', function(){
        if( !$("#moraleducation").val() ) { 
        $(this).closest('.form-group').addClass('has-error');

        }else{
        $(this).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-error');
        }
    });

      $('body').on('click', '#update', function(){
        if( !$("#moraleducation").val() ) { 

          $(this).closest('.form-group').addClass('has-error');

        }else{
        $(this).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-error');
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 $('body').on('click', '#update', function(){
    $(this).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-error');
    if( !$("#moraleducation").val() || !$("#education").val() ) { 
      $(this).closest('.form-group').addClass('has-error');
    }
 });
```